# Synonym for accepting turn of events?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word to describe how, initially, a person boldly accepting the unpleasant turn of events later sadly accepts it as fate and moves on?

Comment: To give an idea of what you are after, you should include a sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: *fatalistic* if you want to know why I suggest this look it up in your dictionary, I don't have time to do that right now.

Comment: Yes Yosef Baskin

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Acquiesce
- Resign (to their fate)
- Submit (to circumstances)
- Surrender (to their fate)